# Regex to find the second occurance of an entry

Tags: python, regex

i am no expert in regex. Therefore, my skill set is beaten. Consider the following text:

```
[SectionTitle0]
...
Name: NameOfTechC
...

[SectionTitle1]
...
Name: NameOfZoneC
...
```

I am interested in extracting the name of Tech-C and Zone-C using regex. This looks like a config-section-party, though I might use a library to parse configs. But this extract is part of a even bigger file. In consequence, config-parsers does not work here.

Currently, I extract the name with `Name:\s?(.+)`. Using `re.findall` in python returns a list  containing both names. Is there a way to use something like

```
TechC_name: regex1
ZoneC_name: regex2
```

that returns the list for either the Tech-C name or the Zone-C name?

**[Update]**
I want to clarify some points. The position of 'Name:' is not fixed, therefore it is possible that same points are listed before, and same after, the entry. I updated my question.

I recognised that sometimes SectionTitle0 (former 'Tech-C') and SectionTitle1 (former 'Zone-C') are identically. That makes it a little bit more complicated. May be there is a way to build a regex that fits the first occurrence of 'Name:' and a regex matching the second (or n-th) occurrence of 'Name:'.

Comment: can you give the expected result according to the example, to let reader understand your intention more clearly?

Comment: I want to separate regex for getting Tech-C oder Zone-C name. Currently, I have one that returns both names; without distinguishing their occurrences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Regex:

```
\[([^\]]*)\][\r\n]+(?:(?!Name:).*[\r\n]+)*?Name:\s*(.*)
```

Efficiently captures section title and name into groups `\1` and `\2`.

### Implementation

```
import re

data  = """[SectionTitle0]
...
Name: NameOfTechC
...

[SectionTitle1]
...
Name: NameOfZoneC
...
"""

regexStr = r'\[([^\]]*)\][\r\n]+(?:(?!Name:).*[\r\n]+)*?Name:\s*(.*)'
regex    = re.compile(regexStr)
regex.findall(data)
```

Comment: I'll give it a try these days.

Answer (score 0):

The two regexes you are looking for are:

TechC_name:

```
re.findall(r"\[Tech-C\]\nName: (.*?)\n", s)
```

ZoneC_name:

```
re.findall(r"\[Zone-C\]\nName: (.*?)\n", s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the output in following format easily:-

```
[(section1, name1), (section2, name2), ...]
```

By following regex implementation:-

```
import re
re.findall(r"\[(\S+)\]\nName: (\w+)", t)
```

Output will be:-

```
[('Tech-C', 'NameOfTechC'), ('Zone-C', 'NameOfZoneC')]
```